# How can I query Wikidata for a label and optional image without further constraints?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I made a derivation of [the cats with images example](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Noch%20mehr%20Katzen%2C%20mit%20Bildern%0A%23added%20before%202016-10%0A%0A%23defaultView%3AImageGrid%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fpic%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ146%20.%0A%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fpic%0ASERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D) where I query for a specific cat, in particular its label and a possible image ([in the web interface](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fpic%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3Fitem%20%3D%20wd%3AQ17000472%20%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fpic%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D)):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?pic
WHERE {
    FILTER ( ?item = wd:Q17000472 ) .
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?pic . }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

I do not care whether it's a cat as I just want to query basic info of any entity. Including such constraint (`?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146 .`) would actually give a result, but again the entity could just be anything.

Am I deducing correctly that a `WHERE` statement in `SPARQL` expects at least one 'unoptional' triple? What would be a good pattern to query optional properties of a specific entity without any knowledge about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) instead of `FILTER` to provide inline data, even if query optimizer is as smart as in Wikidata's Blazegraph:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?pic WHERE {
    VALUES (?item) { (wd:Q17000472) }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?pic }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fpic%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%20%28wd%3AQ17000472%29%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fpic%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D)

> Am I deducing correctly that a WHERE statement in SPARQL expects at least one 'unoptional' triple?

Rather, you shouldn't start with `OPTIONAL`. Evaluation starts from the so-called universal mapping, if the `OPTIONAL` block is not able to retrieve any results this step simply retains the universal mapping.

See also [In SPARQL, Order Matters](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Order_Matters#A_Simple_Example), example Q1b. DBpedia's Virtuoso also [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253772/7879193) this convention.

Fortunately, `VALUES` decide this problem, at least on Wikidata's Blazegraph.

If you are still looking for properties that all Q-entities possess, then [check](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format) `wikibase:statements`, `wikibase:sitelinks`, `wikibase:identifiers`, `schema:version` and `schema:dateModified`.

Comment: Hi Stanislav - pinging you here! https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13550/1511